# How to use arrow key to go from one text box to another text box in a Listview?

Tags: c#, wpf, listview

I have a listview that presenting through itemtemplate .itemtemplate contains a textbox ,so if multiple rows are coming then i want to focus textbox through arrow keys.
now am used this code

```
    private void txtBillRate_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            if (e.Key == Key.Up|| e.Key==Key.Down)
            {
                MoveToNextUIElement(e);                   
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            throw;
        }
    }

    void MoveToNextUIElement(KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        // Creating a FocusNavigationDirection object and setting it to a
        // local field that contains the direction selected.
        FocusNavigationDirection focusDirection = FocusNavigationDirection.Next;

        // MoveFocus takes a TraveralReqest as its argument.
        TraversalRequest request = new TraversalRequest(focusDirection);

        // Gets the element with keyboard focus.
        UIElement elementWithFocus = Keyboard.FocusedElement as UIElement;

        // Change keyboard focus.
        if (elementWithFocus != null)
        {
            if (elementWithFocus.MoveFocus(request)) e.Handled = true;
        }
    }
```

using this code loosing focus from listview.